# Undefined index in persistance collection from Doctrine ORM Cache

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I have the same annotations to others ManyToOne relationships and works fine, but with this one occurs this error from doctrine cache. I'm stuck in this. It's like the doctrine doesn't knew the `inversedBy` annotation.

The error track:

> file: /var/www/html/clipp/Backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>
> line: 2917
>
> message:   Undefined index: 000000003cb11e66000000006a2469c1

The ClientPromotion entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ApplicationClientPromotion")
 * @ORM\Cache(usage="READ_WRITE")
 */
class ClientPromotion
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Model\Client", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="phoneCollection")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
 * @ORM\Cache(usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 *
 */
public $client;
```

The Client entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ApplicationClient"})
 * @ORM\Cache(usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 */
class Client
{
/* OTHER ATTRIBUTES */

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="Application\Model\ClientPromotion",
 *     mappedBy="client",
 *     cascade={"all"},
 *     orphanRemoval=true,
 *     fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @ORM\Cache(usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public $clientPromotionCollection;
```

The error occurs when I call a closure to filter the collection:

```
$freePricePromotions = $client->clientPromotionCollection->filter(function ($entry) {
    // some logic
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: It's about doctrine ORM cache issue, probably due wrong cache annotations. I don't see relation with this linked issue

Comment: @aynber: No, it is not. This is mainly a Doctrine issue, it just causes the same error message. Please read carefully before close-voting.

Comment: @EuclécioJosiasRodrigues: Is it possible that you’re accessing entities after having detached them or after `clear`ing the entity manager?